# Unity C# Transferring image to another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on this app for a while and i'm stuck in here on transferring an image to another scene. for example:

I have this First Scene --> and I have a button to execute the image to another scene. and here is my code in here:

```
 public void transferThisImage(){
   SecondScene theImage = GetComponent<SecondScene>();
   theImage.secondSceneImage.gameObject.setactive(true); 
   }
```

Then I have this Second Scene --> which will accept the command of the button of the first scene. which has the code:

```
public Image secondSceneImage;
```

It returns null, and also i've tried changing the image to gameobject it didn't work as well. anyone had this problem before? any help will be appreciated thank you very much

Comment: Could you please share a minimum testable example of your code? It's hard to say something without knowing how are the variables declared or used.

Comment: hello @RodrigoRodrigues the variable is on top, that is my only variable.can I have a question? is there any possibilities in unity to transfer an UI or an Image to another scene?

Comment: I can't find any source code or help that can provide me some of the logic..

Comment: What is a SecondScene? Is it a custom component? From where are you calling transferThisImage? It doesn't seem you are doing anything with Unity scenes at all

Comment: It is the scene before the 1st scene i created on the scenes folder. btw do you have any idea on transferring image? any code or functionalities? I've tried making them as a prefabs but when I build and run it into my device the prefabs does not work. although it works on the editor. weird huh.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/unity-5-what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes